# Lilypond: Spacing between notes/lyrics

Tags: spacing, lilypond

When I process this code using Lilypond 2.18, the lyrics on the last line are spaced too far apart to be legible as a single word.

```
\version "2.18.0"
\include "english.ly"

\relative bf' {
\key df \major

gf'8 [ff] ef df ef2 c8 df ef2. df8 c bf2. \bar "" \break
gf8 [af] bf c ~ c1 ef,8 [f!] bf af gf1 }

\addlyrics { A - ja - nar ma - - -ha __ _ _ pa - - - -ri - - - choy }
```

How can I lessen the space between syllables on the last line?

Comment: Also, when writing a code sample inside a question here at Stack Overflow, please add it as "Code Sample" instead of normal text (you can do this by selecting the part of your question which contains the code and then clicking on the icon "{ }"). It makes your code much more readable to other users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using the lyrics slashes in the way they were designed to be used. When writing your lyrics with `\addlyrics`, you should enter a `--` or a `__` only once between syllables, not several as in your code. LilyPond will extend it below as many notes as necessary as long as you slur the notes properly. Example:

```
\version "2.18.0" 
{
  c'4 d'( e' f' g'2) a'( b'4 c'') d''2 e''1
}
\addlyrics { Some ly -- rics, __ foo bar! }
```

The code above produces:

[image]

Also, if you want to hide the slurs in that staff, simply add the statement: `\override Staff.Slur.stencil = ##f`

---

Below you will find your example with the lyrics corrected. Also notice that you have some rhythmic problems (in the first bar of the second system, you have more notes than a 4/4 time signature should have, while in the next bar you have less. Apparently you are using the wrong time signature, or you forgot to split that whole note into two half notes.

```
\version "2.18.0" 
\include "english.ly"

\relative bf' { 
  \key df \major
  \override Staff.Slur.stencil = ##f
  gf'8[( ff]) ef( df) ef2 
  c8( df ef2.) df8( c bf2.) \bar "" \break 
  gf8( [af] bf c ~ c1)
  ef,8[( f!] bf af) 
  gf1 
}

\addlyrics { A -- ja -- nar ma -- ha __ pa -- ri -- choy }
```

Comment: For more information on how to add lyrics, please refer to [LilyPond's documentation](http://www.lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/learning/aligning-lyrics-to-a-melody)